# command prompt "killall code" not working. I want to close VScode with command prompt in windows 10

Tags: cmd, command-line

What is the command line code to close VScode? Someone write that `killall code` is the code close VScode, but it doesn't work on my laptop. Is there any other code to close VScode with command prompt code?

Answer (score 3):

`killall` is (typically) a UNIX command. On Windows can be used the `taskkill.exe` command which is part of the OS.

```
taskkill.exe /IM code.exe
```

Not using the `/F` option (= force) gives VS Code the chance to exit gracefully and closer "resembles" the default of `killall` on UNIX (which would be `SIGTERM`, not `SIGKILL`). If you unconditionally want to reap the processes - potential data loss included - use `/F` (which is somewhat identical to `SIGKILL` on UNIX).

(See the [taskkill documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill) for details.)